# What is the remainder when $1! + 2! + 3! +\cdots+ 1000!$ is divided by $12$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial, integers

What is the remainder when $$1! + 2! + 3! +\cdots+ 1000!$$ is divided by $12$.

I have tried to find the answer using the Binomial Theorem but that doesn't help.
How will we do this?

Please help.

Comment: I'd love to see how you used the Binomial Theorem.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Hint**: Every term from $12!$ onward is divisible by $12$, so they don't matter.

Comment: actually, every term from $4!$ onward is divisible by $12$, too

Comment: Every element from $4!$ onwards is divisible by 12

Comment: I think the answer is 9. Right!

Comment: So nice :-) Beatiful.

Answer (score 47):

If $n\ge 4$, then $4!=24$ divides $n!$ $-$ in particular $12$ divides $n!$ when $\ge 4$.

Thus
$$
1!+2!+\cdots+1000!=1!+2!+3! \!\!\!\!\pmod{12}=9\!\!\!\!\pmod{12}.
$$